# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'main'

Tags: ros, roscore, python3, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I installed ROS via the instructions on installing on Mac OSX with no errors during installation. I need ROS to work with Python 3.2.2 (it needs to integrate with MORSE and therefore with Blender, and they both use 3.2.2), so I fixed all of the generic print statements needing parentheses, but then I get to this error. I've uninstalled and reinstalled, as well as the ever typical rebooting, and it is still not fixed.

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/o2wtf2o/ros/ros/bin/roscore", line 36, in 
roslaunch.main(['roscore', '--core']+sys.argv[1:])
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'main'

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12201/attributeerror:-%27module%27-object-has-no-attribute-%27main%27/) by [mike6426](https://answers.ros.org/users/1488/mike6426/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-12-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2012-02-20**:
FYI: you still need to run the ROS command-line tools with Python 2.  The MORSE/Blender fixes only apply the the underlying communication libraries.  Thus, run MORSE with Py3k, run ROS with Python 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From @kwc

FYI: you still need to run the ROS command-line tools with Python 2. The MORSE/Blender fixes only apply the the underlying communication libraries. Thus, run MORSE with Py3k, run ROS with Python 2.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-05-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What version of ROS are you trying to use?  As far as I know many of the Python3 compatibility fixes were integrated into ROS Electric.  You might try to update to that version.

If you are using Electric, how did you install Python3 and can you provide us with the PYTHON_PATH?

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2012-02-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1